# Setting the record straight on google OpenID Connect for chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-openid

I have developed a chrome extension and I would like to charge the clients a monthly subscriptions through Google App store.

After doing some research in the developer's documentation on google chrome I have tried numerous variations to make it work.  Unfortunately I dont even remember every route I took because I followed outdated and - presumably - updated instructions, and I got errors all the time. Now i'm just so confused and I'm really tired to get started blindly and failing again.

The best thing would be if someone here can just set the record straight once and for all and create a file with clear and detailed instructions along with tested working code that I need to include in my files. I'll will follow those instructions closely, and if I encounter any errors along the way I'll ask it here on the discussion thread so you people can guide me through on how to overcome the errors and make this work.

Lets start from square one and take it one step at a time with your guidance!

Thanks A lot

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Incude code (yes you must show us exactly what you tried): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302091/2213940. Write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask